# I need to split a string of characters "AAABCAAABCDEAA" such that it would result in "AA" "ABCAA" "ABCDEAA"

Tags: c++

I need to split a string of characters "AAABCAAABCDEAA" such that it would result  in "AA" "ABCAA" "ABCDEAA"  where "AA" represents the end of a string.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`substr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) methods of `std::string`, eg:

```cpp
std::string s = "AAABCAAABCDEAA";
std::string::size_type start = 0, pos;
while ((pos = s.find("AA", start)) != std::string::npos)
{
    pos += 2;
    std::string s1 = s.substr(start, pos-start);
    // use s1 as needed...
    start = pos;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/E0Jq6C)